# Долгое выполнение команды в Wordpress, как поправить?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Уважаемые специалисты, такой вот вопрос.

Есть плагин для голосования с помощью 5 звезд, называется WP-postratings

Я добавил (между 547 и 548 строчкой) в файл [wp-postratings.php](https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-postratings/blob/master/wp-postratings.php) проверку при голосовании за 2 и менее звезду из 5. Вот код:

```
if($rate < 2) {
                printf(__('<span style="color:red"><strong>текст с просьбой уточнить почему такая низкая оценка</strong></span>'), $post_id);
          $emails_ntl = get_option('admin_email');
          $title_ntl = wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_title($post_id));
          $url_ntl = get_permalink($post_id);
          $message_ntl = "\n\nСсылка на пост {$url_ntl}\n\n Оценка {$rate}";
          wp_mail($emails_ntl, "Оповещение о оценке «{$title_ntl}»", $message_ntl);
                exit();
            }
```

Ситуация такая: если убрать **wp_mail**, то текстовое сообщение (которое "текст с просьбой уточнить почему такая низкая оценка") выводится на странице моментально при голосовании. А если добавить wp_mail, то с существенной задержкой, где-то полторы секунды выводится текстовое сообщение на странице. Как убрать эту задержку?

Comment: Видимо, какие-то проблемы при отправке письма. Предложу код уведомления о низкой оценке выполнить отдельным запросом после отрабатывания плагина. Да и править напрямую что-то в плагине не самый лучший вариант, при обновлении добавленный код затрется

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись. В плагине я ещё в нескольких местах отредактировал. И я вношу правки после обновления плагина, благо оно раз в полгода происходит. С этим проблемы нет.  Как можно добавить отдельный запрос, чтобы сообщение моментально показывалось посетителю сайта и не было задержки?

Comment: например, можно вынести проверку оценки в JS, получается, что и пользователь увидит сообщение сразу, как проголосует, и отправку письма админу можно сделать отдельным AJAX-запросом, который выполнится в фоне и не будет ничего затормаживать